# Guidance on entity reference - tokens or token parsing tools suggestions?

Tags: entities, tokens

I have 3 content types - Organization, Site and Station. Stations related to a Site. Sites related to an Organization.  A user can update is 'location' to show where they are working that day.

I use a token to show the user's current 'location'. I can't seem to parse the location to reflect the Organization relationship.

EG; user is at gate 1. Gate 1 is part of site 'Campus'.  Campus is part of site 'UC Berkeley'.

I get perfect results for Site : [current-user:field_current_location:entity:field_reference_location]
and I get perfect results for Station: [current-user:field_current_location]
but I can't get the correct token to show the current related Organization.
My latest attempt was : [current-user:field_current_location:entity:field_reference_organization:entity]

Suggestions? is there a token parse module that shows values realtime I can rely on?

Comment: Try `[current-user:field_current_location:entity:field_reference_organization]` OR `[current-user:field_current_location:entity:field_reference_organization:root:name]`

Comment: thanks.  I was able to get it doing some trial and error effort - in case this helps some else: 
current-user:field_current_location:entity:field_reference_location:entity:field_org_reference]
and to get afield from the 3rd array: [current-user:field_current_location:entity:field_reference_location:entity:field_org_reference:entity:field_short_org_name]